# make a function that counts object in an array

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code which counts object in an array, and the code works, but when I try to make it an function it disappears and I do not know why.

I want to make it an function so I can put it in a another function.

```
    var markers = [
      {
        type:"Chocolate",
        name:"KitKat",
        group:"candy",
        icon:"candy",
        coords:[5246,8980],
      },
      {
        type:"Fruit",
        name:"Orange",
        group:"fruits",
        icon:"fruis",
        coords:[9012,5493],
      },
      {
        type:"Fruit",
        name:"Banana",
        group:"fruits",
        icon:"fruis",
        coords:[9012,5493],
      },
      {
        type:"Food",
        name:"Rice",
        group:"foods",
        icon:"foods",
        coords:[6724,9556],
      },
      {
        type:"Food",
        name:"Meat",
        group:"foods",
        icon:"foods",
        coords:[6724,9556],
      },
      {
        type:"Food",
        name:"Beam",
        group:"foods",
        icon:"foods",
        coords:[6724,9556],
      },
      {
        type:"Liquid",
        name:"Water",
        group:"liquids",
        icon:"liquids",
        coords:[6724,9556],
      },
      {
        type:"Liquid",
        name:"Coffe",
        group:"liquids",
        icon:"liquids",
        coords:[6724,9556],
      },
    ];

    var count = {}

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      count[markers[i].type] = count[markers[i].type] + 1 || 1 ;
    }
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(count);
```

```
    function make(){
    var pg = '<table>'
        for(i = 0;i < markers.length; i++){
           pg += '<td>' + ??? + '</td>'; // I would like to put it here
            og += '</tr>';
        }
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = pg;
    }
```

and I would also like to remove `JSON.stringify` because I am new to programming so more vanilla JavaScript would be the best.

Comment: JSON.stringify is the way vanilla Javascript converts a JSON to a string. About your question, please do what you want in plain HTML and then try to take it to Javascript, we can't help if we don't know what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine, but you have to actually call the function.

Also, `JSON.stringify()` ***is*** vanilla JavaScript.

However, to get the type of output you are looking for, you'll need to loop over the resulting `count` object. Tables are generally discouraged, but you can achieve the same layout by sizing elements with CSS as shown here.

Also, to make the function reusable, we can pass `markers` into it as an argument instead of having the function always working with just that one object.

```js
var markers = [
  {
    type:"Chocolate",
    name:"KitKat",
    group:"candy",
    icon:"candy",
    coords:[5246,8980],
  },
  {
    type:"Fruit",
    name:"Orange",
    group:"fruits",
    icon:"fruis",
    coords:[9012,5493],
  },
  {
    type:"Fruit",
    name:"Banana",
    group:"fruits",
    icon:"fruis",
    coords:[9012,5493],
  },
  {
    type:"Food",
    name:"Rice",
    group:"foods",
    icon:"foods",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    type:"Food",
    name:"Meat",
    group:"foods",
    icon:"foods",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    type:"Food",
    name:"Beam",
    group:"foods",
    icon:"foods",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    type:"Liquid",
    name:"Water",
    group:"liquids",
    icon:"liquids",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
  {
    type:"Liquid",
    name:"Coffe",
    group:"liquids",
    icon:"liquids",
    coords:[6724,9556],
  },
];

let output = document.getElementById('data');

function counter(obj){
  var count = {}

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    count[obj[i].type] = count[obj[i].type] + 1 || 1 ;
  }
  
  // Now that the result object is populated,
  // this function has done its job, but we 
  // want that resulting object to be used in
  // order to create the layout on the page
  // so this function will return it to the caller
  return count;
}

// Run the counter function and pass it our starting object
// then store the resulting object.
let totalCounts = counter(markers); 

// This function reqquires an object to be passed in
// and it will make the page layout. So, we'll pass
// the object we got back from running the counter function
function make(obj){
  // Now that the object is created, loop over it
  for(var prop in obj){
    // Create a new span for to hold the type and configure it:
    let type = document.createElement("span");
    type.classList.add("type");
    type.textContent = prop;  // prop is the name of the property
    
    // Now one for the count
    let counter = document.createElement("span");
    counter.classList.add("type");
    counter.textContent = obj[prop]; // count[prop] gets the value of the property
    
    // And something to hold the spans
    let row = document.createElement("div");
    
    // Inject the new elements into the document
    row.appendChild(type);
    row.appendChild(counter);
    output.append(row);
  }
}

make(totalCounts); // And then call it!
```

```css
.type, .row { display:inline-block; width:100px; }
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

Comment: "*`JSON.stringify()` **is** vanilla JavaScript*" also worth noting that the code wouldn't work without it. Or rather, you'd have to re-implement the functionality and it's going to be even more complex.

Comment: But when i put it in function make() is does not work?

Comment: It would be more instructive if you showed how to make `markers` a function parameter, rather than hard-coding the global variable.

Comment: @CodingWomen Make `counter()` return the `count` object, then loop over that in `make()`.

Comment: @Barmar Done. I sometimes hesitate to add additional features that the OP didn't ask about as to not over complicate the solution. But here, it makes sense.

Comment: I am sorry i'm not sure what you mean? can you show me I am very new to this

Comment: @CodingWomen I am doing what Baramar suggested, just doing it in one function, rather than two.

Comment: @CodingWomen `make()` should be looping over the `count` variable, not `markers`, so it shows the result of the counts.

Comment: @CodingWomen I've updated the answer to show how you can do this with two functions.